# VK SDK Серверные методы API как вызывать?

Tags: java, android, c#, вконтакте, windows-phone-8

Добрый вечер)
Пишу небольшое приложение с использованием VK SDK. Необходимы серверные методы API secure.* (например secure.sendNotification). Для их вызова нужно получать другой token с помощью специальной схемы, которая плохо описана в документации.

```
'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + CLIENT_SECRET + '&v=5.50&grant_type=client_credentials'
```

где я вставляю свой client_id и client_secret. Только не знаю, как вызвать этот запрос и получить обратно токен, чтобы его использовать в методах secure.* .

Может быть кто-то знает, как это сделать? Можно пример и на java и на C#.

Comment: Это одноразовое действие. Не имеет смысл его автоматизировать. Открываете браузер, вставляете ссылку, жмете "подтвердить" - на экране появляется `access_token` - вставляете его в код/конфиг своего приложения, да и всё.

Comment: Так мне нужно, чтобы пользователь приложения получал это токен и пользовался их. Думаю, будет неудобно ему делать какие-то странные вещи с браузером и токеном

Comment: Они не должны предоставлятся клиенту ни в коем случае. Иначе есть вероятность не хило так залезть в денежный долг перед VK, либо довольно быстро выхватить бан приложения, а то и аккаунта разработчика. Их нужно хранить на вашем защищенном сервере, который и будет обрабатывать запросы пользователей в соответствии с необходимой вам логикой.

Comment: Все же я что-то не понимаю, как мне использовать эти secure методы. В документации написано нужно пройти такую аутентификацию и полученный токен отправлять в запросе secure. А примеров - "НОЛЬ"

Comment: @strevg, если один из предложенных вам ответов решает заявленную задачу, то вы можете отметить его "верным"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример на Java с помощью либы `OkHttp`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

            Request.Builder request = new Request.Builder();

            String CLIENT_ID = "Цифры тут из настроек приложения в ВК";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "Секретный код из настроек приложения в ВК";
            request.url("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&v=5.50&grant_type=client_credentials");

            Response response = client.newCall(request.build()).execute();

            String answer = response.body().string();
            Log.e("LOG", answer);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Выведет это:

> {"access_token":"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf8sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf","expires_in":0}

Так что вам надо лишь прочитать ответ ВК на ваш запрос. Вот тут есть ещё примеры Java кода по вытаскиванию инфы из ответа, получаемого по URL: [тык](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/)

Собственно, эту же строку-ответ ВК вы можете увидеть и просто вбив получившийся адрес в браузер.

Comment: Не спел еще проверить